# rosserial and wireless communication

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using [APC220](http://www.dfrobot.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=57) Radio Communication Module on my arduino atmega2560, in order to communicate with my computer wirelessly.
i have written a simple publisher/subscriber node for my arduino using arduino ide and ros_lib, it's works fine using usb to serial cable, but when i'm using APC220(which is actually acts as an serial interface, conntected toRX/TX pins), i am getting following errors:

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1410187017.536715] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125 
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1410187017.538328] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125
[WARN] [WallTime: 1410187017.549967] Serial Port read returned short (expected 16 bytes, received 13 instead).
[WARN] [WallTime: 1410187017.550437] Serial Port read failure: 
[INFO] [WallTime: 1410187017.550810] Packet Failed :  Failed to read msg data
[INFO] [WallTime: 1410187017.551095] msg len is 16
```

I am almost sure about my hardware settings and baud rates, because it's works with a single publisher, my problem is a node with subscriber and publisher working simultaneously.

Is there any tips about using rosserial_arduino with wireless modules?
Is there any body who has experienced APC220 modules with ROS and Arduino?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192183/rosserial-and-wireless-communication/) by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 717 on 2014-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently had this problem. I don't think it has anything to do with that specific radio: I was using an Arduino Uno and Xbee module, communicating with my laptop and it's Xbee. My issue was that the initial communication to set up the publishers and subscribers, was failing.
In my case, it was failing because the Arduino's serial buffer was too small.

---

Originally posted by [TimboInSpace](https://answers.ros.org/users/11216/timboinspace/) with karma: 141 on 2014-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0